# Using TypeScript in VS Code giving Canvas errors on latest version

Tags: typescript, dom, visual-studio-code, canvas

I am writing some Canvas code in TypeScript for my app and get the following error:

```
Property 'wrapText' does not exist on type 'CanvasRenderingContext2D'.ts(2339)
```

This is coming from the line:

```
CanvasRenderingContext2D.prototype.wrapText = function(text, x, y, maxWidth, lineHeight)
```

I guess I can add a declaration in the lib.dom.d.ts file which is in the node_modules extensions part of VS Code.  Is this the only way to fix it? I am curious why it wasn't included. I am running the April 2021 version of VS Code as I just upgraded it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't find a reference that demonstrates there SHOULD be an existing `wrapText` definition on the context, and it wouldn't necessarily be writable even if there was such a member property.

I think this monkey-patching pattern is adding a new property which doesn't exist at all before.

I interpret this as being the normal excess property check behavior of typescript meaning you can't assign unexpected properties to instances of pre-defined types.

https://riptutorial.com/html5-canvas/example/18590/wrapping-text-into-paragraphs states there IS NO pre-existing implementation and adopts a similar pattern (in javascript where there are no excess property checks so no error).

Without manipulating any node_modules or VSCode metadata you can still arrange to make this optional property valid on a CanvasRenderingContext2D locally to your project by using Global Augmentation... https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#global-augmentation

Comment: You are correct. I figured it out and it is my mistake and there is no reference to .wrapText as it is someone else's made up function. I just have to declare it differently. Thanks.