# Grouping x-axis labels on multiple lines on a ChartJS with an extra dimension

Tags: javascript, node.js, plugins, chart.js, xscale

Please help me

I have the following graph, where I have where each user belongs to a different area

I was wondering if there is a way to group the information by "user role" and once it is grouped, separate it by a line on the "x" axis

I am quite confused because supposedly if it is possible to do it according to the accepted answer in this question [Grouping y-axis labels on multiple lines on a ChartJS with an extra dimension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67275805/grouping-y-axis-labels-on-multiple-lines-on-a-chartjs-with-an-extra-dimension)

But according to other answers from the community that is impossible with chartjs

How to make it possible? It's called Multi Level Category Labels

So I want to be able to modify the grid of the labels in X-Scale to separate the areas via a line and also add a sub-label. Something like this:

[image: image1]

I leave the [json](https://github.com/IzliaFlorentino/jsonData) and the code of my graph, I am using charjs-node-canvas to configure it and chartjs-plugin-datalabels to modify the labels of my graph. The technologies that I am using is nodejs with express using typescript and for my HTML template I am using Handlebars

```
 const canvasRenderService = new ChartJSNodeCanvas({
        width: 1000,
        height: 650,
        chartCallback: (ChartJS) => {
            ChartJS.register(require('chartjs-plugin-datalabels'))
        }
    });

    const mkChart = await canvasRenderService.renderToBuffer({
        type: 'bar',
        data: {
            labels: labels,
            datasets: [{
                type: 'line',
                label: '% ACTIVITY',
                backgroundColor: '#FF7605',
                borderColor: '#FF7605',
                data: lineBar,
                datalabels: {
                    anchor: 'start',
                    align: 'center',
                    clamp: true,
                    backgroundColor: '#FF7605',
                    color: 'white',
                    font: {
                        weight: 'bold'
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                type: 'bar',
                label: 'WEEKLY SUMMARY OF HOURS',
                backgroundColor: '#222A35',
                borderColor: '#222A35',
                data: barHorizontal,
                datalabels: {
                    rotation: 270,
                    padding: 10
                }

            },
            {
                type: 'bar',
                label: 'HOURS',
                backgroundColor: '#008582',
                borderColor: '#008582',
                data: colbWeekly,
                datalabels: {
                    anchor: 'end',
                    align: 'top',
                    clamp: true,
                    backgroundColor: '#008582',
                    color: 'white',
                    font: {
                        weight: 'bold'
                    }
                }
            }]
        },
        options: {
            plugins: {
                datalabels: {
                    color: 'white',
                    font: {
                        weight: 'bold'
                    },
                },
                title: {
                    display: true,
                    text: 'AVERAGE WEEKLY HOURS'
                }
            },
            elements: {
                line: {
                    fill: false
                }
            },
            scales: {
                x: {
                    stacked: true,
                    ticks: {
                        minRotation: 90
                    },
                    grid: {
                        display: false
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    });
```

**DEMO**

```js
const apidata = [{
    "id": 6430591403,
    "task_id": 110578536,
    "user_id": 854500,
    "keyboard": 872,
    "mouse": 2123,
    "input_tracked": 20149,
    "manual": 9000,
    "idle": 0,
    "resumed": 0,
    "billable": 20149,
    "created_at": "2022-09-02T17:40:03.167232Z",
    "updated_at": "2022-09-03T11:00:24.381152Z",
    "username": "user1",
    "status": "active",
    "weekly_hours": 24,
    "three_weekly_hours": 12,
    "summaryWeekly": 29149,
    "summaryoverallWeekly": 2827,
    "dayliHoursDaily": 4,
    "summaryHoursTrackedWeekly": 8,
    "percentageHours": 2.024236111111111,
    "activityWeekly": 0,
    "percentageActivityWeekly": 2,
    "rolTittle": "DEV",
    "rolPriority": 0,
    "summaryStarts": 0,
    "percentActivityW": 8,
    "avergeHourWeekly": 2.025
  },
  {
    "id": 6418099795,
    "task_id": 110964243,
    "user_id": 1169488,
    "keyboard": 12454,
    "mouse": 21282,
    "input_tracked": 56867,
    "manual": 9000,
    "idle": 0,
    "resumed": 634,
    "billable": 56867,
    "created_at": "2022-09-01T14:12:47.422537Z",
    "updated_at": "2022-09-02T11:00:52.334795Z",
    "username": "user2",
    "status": "active",
    "weekly_hours": 44,
    "three_weekly_hours": 20,
    "summaryWeekly": 65867,
    "summaryoverallWeekly": 30906,
    "dayliHoursDaily": 8,
    "summaryHoursTrackedWeekly": 18,
    "percentageHours": 4.574097222222222,
    "activityWeekly": 0,
    "percentageActivityWeekly": 12,
    "rolTittle": "DEV",
    "rolPriority": 0,
    "summaryStarts": 0,
    "percentActivityW": 35,
    "avergeHourWeekly": 4.575
  },
  {
    "id": 6436682459,
    "task_id": 111277830,
    "user_id": 854472,
    "keyboard": 3650,
    "mouse": 53335,
    "input_tracked": 76184,
    "manual": 0,
    "idle": 0,
    "resumed": 0,
    "billable": 76184,
    "created_at": "2022-09-03T14:04:18.371347Z",
    "updated_at": "2022-09-04T11:00:12.456776Z",
    "username": "user3",
    "status": "active",
    "weekly_hours": 44,
    "three_weekly_hours": 20,
    "summaryWeekly": 76184,
    "summaryoverallWeekly": 55852,
    "dayliHoursDaily": 8,
    "summaryHoursTrackedWeekly": 21,
    "percentageHours": 5.290555555555556,
    "activityWeekly": 0,
    "percentageActivityWeekly": 18,
    "rolTittle": "DEV",
    "rolPriority": 0,
    "summaryStarts": 2,
    "percentActivityW": 54,
    "avergeHourWeekly": 5.29
  },
  {
    "id": 6418143504,
    "task_id": 111039935,
    "user_id": 957706,
    "keyboard": 8128,
    "mouse": 26665,
    "input_tracked": 56130,
    "manual": 0,
    "idle": 0,
    "resumed": 0,
    "billable": 56130,
    "created_at": "2022-09-01T14:20:38.428547Z",
    "updated_at": "2022-09-02T11:00:53.895079Z",
    "username": "user4",
    "status": "active",
    "weekly_hours": 44,
    "three_weekly_hours": 20,
    "summaryWeekly": 56130,
    "summaryoverallWeekly": 31989,
    "dayliHoursDaily": 8,
    "summaryHoursTrackedWeekly": 16,
    "percentageHours": 3.8979166666666667,
    "activityWeekly": 0,
    "percentageActivityWeekly": 14,
    "rolTittle": "DEV",
    "rolPriority": 0,
    "summaryStarts": 0,
    "percentActivityW": 42,
    "avergeHourWeekly": 3.8975000000000004
  },
  {
    "id": 6436827335,
    "task_id": 110101015,
    "user_id": 854517,
    "keyboard": 5695,
    "mouse": 28077,
    "input_tracked": 62610,
    "manual": 0,
    "idle": 0,
    "resumed": 0,
    "billable": 62610,
    "created_at": "2022-09-03T16:51:44.533355Z",
    "updated_at": "2022-09-04T11:00:10.219855Z",
    "username": "user5",
    "status": "active",
    "weekly_hours": 44,
    "three_weekly_hours": 20,
    "summaryWeekly": 62610,
    "summaryoverallWeekly": 30715,
    "dayliHoursDaily": 8,
    "summaryHoursTrackedWeekly": 17,
    "percentageHours": 4.347916666666666,
    "activityWeekly": 0,
    "percentageActivityWeekly": 12,
    "rolTittle": "DEV",
    "rolPriority": 0,
    "summaryStarts": 0,
    "percentActivityW": 37,
    "avergeHourWeekly": 4.3475
  },
  {
    "id": 6415607157,
    "task_id": 111238271,
    "user_id": 854471,
    "keyboard": 7295,
    "mouse": 14616,
    "input_tracked": 29633,
    "manual": 0,
    "idle": 1571,
    "resumed": 0,
    "billable": 29633,
    "created_at": "2022-09-01T06:17:06.580395Z",
    "updated_at": "2022-09-02T11:01:01.677261Z",
    "username": "user6",
    "status": "active",
    "weekly_hours": 44,
    "three_weekly_hours": 20,
    "summaryWeekly": 29633,
    "summaryoverallWeekly": 19055,
    "dayliHoursDaily": 8,
    "summaryHoursTrackedWeekly": 8,
    "percentageHours": 2.057847222222222,
    "activityWeekly": 0,
    "percentageActivityWeekly": 16,
    "rolTittle": "DEV",
    "rolPriority": 0,
    "summaryStarts": 0,
    "percentActivityW": 31,
    "avergeHourWeekly": 2.0575
  },
  {
    "id": 6438865339,
    "task_id": 110014205,
    "user_id": 1171637,
    "keyboard": 11728,
    "mouse": 24895,
    "input_tracked": 70739,
    "manual": 1620,
    "idle": 0,
    "resumed": 0,
    "billable": 70739,
    "created_at": "2022-09-04T16:03:44.328404Z",
    "updated_at": "2022-09-05T11:00:31.972437Z",
    "username": "user7",
    "status": "active",
    "weekly_hours": 44,
    "three_weekly_hours": 20,
    "summaryWeekly": 72359,
    "summaryoverallWeekly": 30822,
    "dayliHoursDaily": 8,
    "summaryHoursTrackedWeekly": 20,
    "percentageHours": 5.024930555555556,
    "activityWeekly": 0,
    "percentageActivityWeekly": 11,
    "rolTittle": "DEV",
    "rolPriority": 0,
    "summaryStarts": 2,
    "percentActivityW": 31,
    "avergeHourWeekly": 5.0225
  },
  {
    "id": 6429724387,
    "task_id": 111040126,
    "user_id": 854493,
    "keyboard": 13205,
    "mouse": 30058,
    "input_tracked": 56630,
    "manual": 0,
    "idle": 0,
    "resumed": 0,
    "billable": 56630,
    "created_at": "2022-09-02T14:46:58.641008Z",
    "updated_at": "2022-09-03T11:00:13.064762Z",
    "username": "user8",
    "status": "active",
    "weekly_hours": 44,
    "three_weekly_hours": 20,
    "summaryWeekly": 56630,
    "summaryoverallWeekly": 40044,
    "dayliHoursDaily": 8,
    "summaryHoursTrackedWeekly": 16,
    "percentageHours": 3.932638888888889,
    "activityWeekly": 0,
    "percentageActivityWeekly": 18,
    "rolTittle": "DEV",
    "rolPriority": 0,
    "summaryStarts": 0,
    "percentActivityW": 74,
    "avergeHourWeekly": 3.9325
  },
  {
    "id": 6418215334,
    "task_id": 111232314,
    "user_id": 1726823,
    "keyboard": 11761,
    "mouse": 35504,
    "input_tracked": 73802,
    "manual": 862,
    "idle": 0,
    "resumed": 0,
    "billable": 74664,
    "created_at": "2022-09-01T14:32:20.799309Z",
    "updated_at": "2022-09-02T11:00:48.637118Z",
    "username": "user9",
    "status": "active",
    "weekly_hours": 44,
    "three_weekly_hours": 20,
    "summaryWeekly": 74664,
    "summaryoverallWeekly": 43021,
    "dayliHoursDaily": 8,
    "summaryHoursTrackedWeekly": 21,
    "percentageHours": 5.185,
    "activityWeekly": 0,
    "percentageActivityWeekly": 14,
    "rolTittle": "DEV",
    "rolPriority": 0,
    "summaryStarts": 1,
    "percentActivityW": 41,
    "avergeHourWeekly": 5.1850000000000005
  },
  {
    "id": 6436683187,
    "task_id": 110916251,
    "user_id": 957963,
    "keyboard": 2050,
    "mouse": 5530,
    "input_tracked": 13478,
    "manual": 1181,
    "idle": 0,
    "resumed": 0,
    "billable": 14659,
    "created_at": "2022-09-03T14:05:12.543140Z",
    "updated_at": "2022-09-03T15:39:51.279106Z",
    "username": "user10",
    "status": "active",
    "weekly_hours": 44,
    "three_weekly_hours": 20,
    "summaryWeekly": 14659,
    "summaryoverallWeekly": 7182,
    "dayliHoursDaily": 8,
    "summaryHoursTrackedWeekly": 4,
    "percentageHours": 1.017986111111111,
    "activityWeekly": 0,
    "percentageActivityWeekly": 12,
    "rolTittle": "DEV",
    "rolPriority": 0,
    "summaryStarts": 0,
    "percentActivityW": 12,
    "avergeHourWeekly": 1.0175
  },
  {
    "id": 6415608216,
    "task_id": 110169040,
    "user_id": 1476078,
    "keyboard": 23401,
    "mouse": 51185,
    "input_tracked": 99108,
    "manual": 0,
    "idle": 0,
    "resumed": 0,
    "billable": 99108,
    "created_at": "2022-09-01T06:17:26.341286Z",
    "updated_at": "2022-09-02T02:03:01.258835Z",
    "username": "user11",
    "status": "active",
    "weekly_hours": 44,
    "three_weekly_hours": 20,
    "summaryWeekly": 99108,
    "summaryoverallWeekly": 67332,
    "dayliHoursDaily": 8,
    "summaryHoursTrackedWeekly": 28,
    "percentageHours": 6.882499999999999,
    "activityWeekly": 0,
    "percentageActivityWeekly": 17,
    "rolTittle": "DEV",
    "rolPriority": 0,
    "summaryStarts": 6,
    "percentActivityW": 48,
    "avergeHourWeekly": 6.885
  },
  {
    "id": 6436711920,
    "task_id": 111299925,
    "user_id": 1762379,
    "keyboard": 9260,
    "mouse": 27177,
    "input_tracked": 63034,
    "manual": 0,
    "idle": 0,
    "resumed": 0,
    "billable": 63034,
    "created_at": "2022-09-03T14:37:55.058824Z",
    "updated_at": "2022-09-04T11:00:09.826018Z",
    "username": "user12",
    "status": "active",
    "weekly_hours": 44,
    "three_weekly_hours": 20,
    "summaryWeekly": 63034,
    "summaryoverallWeekly": 33416,
    "dayliHoursDaily": 8,
    "summaryHoursTrackedWeekly": 18,
    "percentageHours": 4.377361111111111,
    "activityWeekly": 0,
    "percentageActivityWeekly": 13,
    "rolTittle": "DEV",
    "rolPriority": 0,
    "summaryStarts": 0,
    "percentActivityW": 40,
    "avergeHourWeekly": 4.3774999999999995
  },
  {
    "id": 6438388730,
    "task_id": 111271635,
    "user_id": 1763812,
    "keyboard": 8023,
    "mouse": 34217,
    "input_tracked": 60716,
    "manual": 3056,
    "idle": 0,
    "resumed": 0,
    "billable": 63772,
    "created_at": "2022-09-04T06:11:14.526669Z",
    "updated_at": "2022-09-04T11:00:10.753741Z",
    "username": "user13",
    "status": "active",
    "weekly_hours": 44,
    "three_weekly_hours": 20,
    "summaryWeekly": 63772,
    "summaryoverallWeekly": 39685,
    "dayliHoursDaily": 8,
    "summaryHoursTrackedWeekly": 18,
    "percentageHours": 4.4286111111111115,
    "activityWeekly": 0,
    "percentageActivityWeekly": 16,
    "rolTittle": "DEV",
    "rolPriority": 0,
    "summaryStarts": 0,
    "percentActivityW": 66,
    "avergeHourWeekly": 4.4275
  },
  {
    "id": 6436711572,
    "task_id": 110962406,
    "user_id": 1512574,
    "keyboard": 13031,
    "mouse": 29149,
    "input_tracked": 58021,
    "manual": 0,
    "idle": 0,
    "resumed": 0,
    "billable": 58021,
    "created_at": "2022-09-03T14:37:32.555344Z",
    "updated_at": "2022-09-04T11:00:12.010515Z",
    "username": "user14",
    "status": "active",
    "weekly_hours": 44,
    "three_weekly_hours": 20,
    "summaryWeekly": 58021,
    "summaryoverallWeekly": 35912,
    "dayliHoursDaily": 8,
    "summaryHoursTrackedWeekly": 16,
    "percentageHours": 4.0292361111111115,
    "activityWeekly": 0,
    "percentageActivityWeekly": 15,
    "rolTittle": "DEV",
    "rolPriority": 0,
    "summaryStarts": 0,
    "percentActivityW": 46,
    "avergeHourWeekly": 4.0275
  },
  {
    "id": 6429845321,
    "task_id": 111275770,
    "user_id": 1597423,
    "keyboard": 7547,
    "mouse": 16932,
    "input_tracked": 45344,
    "manual": 9000,
    "idle": 0,
    "resumed": 0,
    "billable": 45344,
    "created_at": "2022-09-02T15:02:22.445061Z",
    "updated_at": "2022-09-02T21:05:15.892875Z",
    "username": "user15",
    "status": "active",
    "weekly_hours": 44,
    "three_weekly_hours": 20,
    "summaryWeekly": 54344,
    "summaryoverallWeekly": 21515,
    "dayliHoursDaily": 8,
    "summaryHoursTrackedWeekly": 15,
    "percentageHours": 3.773888888888889,
    "activityWeekly": 0,
    "percentageActivityWeekly": 10,
    "rolTittle": "SAC",
    "rolPriority": 1,
    "summaryStarts": 0,
    "percentActivityW": 32,
    "avergeHourWeekly": 3.7724999999999995
  },
  {
    "id": 6429886569,
    "task_id": 111300959,
    "user_id": 1005008,
    "keyboard": 9124,
    "mouse": 23219,
    "input_tracked": 47335,
    "manual": 16930,
    "idle": 0,
    "resumed": 0,
    "billable": 64265,
    "created_at": "2022-09-02T15:10:49.050765Z",
    "updated_at": "2022-09-02T15:37:15.995376Z",
    "username": "user16",
    "status": "active",
    "weekly_hours": 44,
    "three_weekly_hours": 20,
    "summaryWeekly": 64265,
    "summaryoverallWeekly": 30503,
    "dayliHoursDaily": 8,
    "summaryHoursTrackedWeekly": 18,
    "percentageHours": 4.462847222222222,
    "activityWeekly": 0,
    "percentageActivityWeekly": 12,
    "rolTittle": "SAC",
    "rolPriority": 1,
    "summaryStarts": 0,
    "percentActivityW": 47,
    "avergeHourWeekly": 4.4625
  },
  {
    "id": 6418406327,
    "task_id": 110056072,
    "user_id": 1005014,
    "keyboard": 3338,
    "mouse": 24665,
    "input_tracked": 51343,
    "manual": 0,
    "idle": 0,
    "resumed": 0,
    "billable": 51343,
    "created_at": "2022-09-01T15:01:36.521321Z",
    "updated_at": "2022-09-01T15:35:14.010868Z",
    "username": "user17",
    "status": "active",
    "weekly_hours": 44,
    "three_weekly_hours": 20,
    "summaryWeekly": 51343,
    "summaryoverallWeekly": 27397,
    "dayliHoursDaily": 8,
    "summaryHoursTrackedWeekly": 14,
    "percentageHours": 3.565486111111111,
    "activityWeekly": 0,
    "percentageActivityWeekly": 13,
    "rolTittle": "SAC",
    "rolPriority": 1,
    "summaryStarts": 0,
    "percentActivityW": 62,
    "avergeHourWeekly": 3.5649999999999995
  },
  {
    "id": 6436728901,
    "task_id": 109755222,
    "user_id": 1846477,
    "keyboard": 9644,
    "mouse": 25906,
    "input_tracked": 64724,
    "manual": 0,
    "idle": 0,
    "resumed": 0,
    "billable": 64724,
    "created_at": "2022-09-03T14:57:43.250737Z",
    "updated_at": "2022-09-03T19:24:22.872994Z",
    "username": "user18",
    "status": "active",
    "weekly_hours": 44,
    "three_weekly_hours": 20,
    "summaryWeekly": 64724,
    "summaryoverallWeekly": 29885,
    "dayliHoursDaily": 8,
    "summaryHoursTrackedWeekly": 18,
    "percentageHours": 4.494722222222222,
    "activityWeekly": 0,
    "percentageActivityWeekly": 12,
    "rolTittle": "DESIGN",
    "rolPriority": 2,
    "summaryStarts": 0,
    "percentActivityW": 34,
    "avergeHourWeekly": 4.495
  },
  {
    "id": null,
    "task_id": null,
    "user_id": 1886674,
    "keyboard": 0,
    "mouse": 0,
    "input_tracked": 0,
    "manual": 0,
    "idle": 0,
    "resumed": 0,
    "billable": 0,
    "created_at": null,
    "updated_at": null,
    "username": "user19",
    "status": "active",
    "weekly_hours": 12.5,
    "three_weekly_hours": 7,
    "summaryWeekly": 0,
    "summaryoverallWeekly": 0,
    "dayliHoursDaily": 3,
    "summaryHoursTrackedWeekly": 0,
    "percentageHours": 0,
    "activityWeekly": 0,
    "percentageActivityWeekly": 0,
    "rolTittle": "DESIGN",
    "rolPriority": 2,
    "summaryStarts": 0,
    "percentActivityW": 0,
    "avergeHourWeekly": 0
  },
  {
    "id": null,
    "task_id": null,
    "user_id": 1931414,
    "keyboard": 0,
    "mouse": 0,
    "input_tracked": 0,
    "manual": 0,
    "idle": 0,
    "resumed": 0,
    "billable": 0,
    "created_at": null,
    "updated_at": null,
    "username": "user20",
    "status": "active",
    "weekly_hours": 12.5,
    "three_weekly_hours": 7,
    "summaryWeekly": 0,
    "summaryoverallWeekly": 0,
    "dayliHoursDaily": 3,
    "summaryHoursTrackedWeekly": 0,
    "percentageHours": 0,
    "activityWeekly": 0,
    "percentageActivityWeekly": 0,
    "rolTittle": "DESIGN",
    "rolPriority": 2,
    "summaryStarts": 0,
    "percentActivityW": 0,
    "avergeHourWeekly": 0
  },
  {
    "id": null,
    "task_id": null,
    "user_id": 766827,
    "keyboard": 0,
    "mouse": 0,
    "input_tracked": 0,
    "manual": 0,
    "idle": 0,
    "resumed": 0,
    "billable": 0,
    "created_at": null,
    "updated_at": null,
    "username": "user21",
    "status": "active",
    "weekly_hours": 12.5,
    "three_weekly_hours": 7,
    "summaryWeekly": 0,
    "summaryoverallWeekly": 0,
    "dayliHoursDaily": 3,
    "summaryHoursTrackedWeekly": 0,
    "percentageHours": 0,
    "activityWeekly": 0,
    "percentageActivityWeekly": 0,
    "rolTittle": "DESIGN",
    "rolPriority": 2,
    "summaryStarts": 0,
    "percentActivityW": 0,
    "avergeHourWeekly": 0
  }
]

const maplabels = apidata.map(element => element.username);
const labels = maplabels;

// DataBar
const mapbarHorizontal = apidata.map(element => element.summaryHoursTrackedWeekly);
const barHorizontal = mapbarHorizontal;
// console.log('labels', barHorizontal);

// LineBar
const maplineBar = apidata.map(element => element.percentActivityW);
const lineBar = maplineBar;

// BarWeeklyHour Colaborador
const mapColbWeekly = apidata.map(element => element.three_weekly_hours);
const colbWeekly = mapColbWeekly;

const chart = new Chart(document.getElementById("chart"), {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: labels,
    datasets: [{
        type: 'line',
        label: '% ACTIVITY',
        backgroundColor: '#FF7605',
        borderColor: '#FF7605',
        data: lineBar,
        datalabels: {
          anchor: 'start',
          align: 'center',
          clamp: true,
          backgroundColor: '#FF7605',
          color: 'white',
          font: {
            weight: 'bold'
          }
        }
      },
      {
        type: 'bar',
        label: 'WEEKLY SUMMARY OF HOURS',
        backgroundColor: '#222A35',
        borderColor: '#222A35',
        data: barHorizontal,
        datalabels: {
          rotation: 270,
          padding: 10
        }

      },
      {
        type: 'bar',
        label: 'HOURS',
        backgroundColor: '#008582',
        borderColor: '#008582',
        data: colbWeekly,
        datalabels: {
          anchor: 'end',
          align: 'top',
          clamp: true,
          backgroundColor: '#008582',
          color: 'white',
          font: {
            weight: 'bold'
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  options: {
    plugins: {
      datalabels: {
        color: 'white',
        font: {
          weight: 'bold'
        },
      },
      title: {
        display: true,
        text: 'AVERAGE WEEKLY HOURS'
      }
    },
    elements: {
      line: {
        fill: false
      }
    },
    scales: {
      x: {
        stacked: true,
        ticks: {
          minRotation: 90
        },
        grid: {
          display: false
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@3.0.0/dist/chart.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-plugin-datalabels"></script>
<div>
  <div id="legend"></div>
  <canvas id="chart"></canvas>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To group the information, in the end the only thing I did was assign an AxisID to my balance, to be able to draw on them and thus use lines to separate my information and add sub labels

```js
const apidata = [{
    "id": 6430591403,
    "task_id": 110578536,
    "user_id": 854500,
    "keyboard": 872,
    "mouse": 2123,
    "input_tracked": 20149,
    "manual": 9000,
    "idle": 0,
    "resumed": 0,
    "billable": 20149,
    "created_at": "2022-09-02T17:40:03.167232Z",
    "updated_at": "2022-09-03T11:00:24.381152Z",
    "username": "user1",
    "status": "active",
    "weekly_hours": 24,
    "three_weekly_hours": 12,
    "summaryWeekly": 29149,
    "summaryoverallWeekly": 2827,
    "dayliHoursDaily": 4,
    "summaryHoursTrackedWeekly": 8,
    "percentageHours": 2.024236111111111,
    "activityWeekly": 0,
    "percentageActivityWeekly": 2,
    "rolTittle": "DEV",
    "rolPriority": 0,
    "summaryStarts": 0,
    "percentActivityW": 8,
    "avergeHourWeekly": 2.025
  },
  {
    "id": 6418215334,
    "task_id": 111232314,
    "user_id": 1726823,
    "keyboard": 11761,
    "mouse": 35504,
    "input_tracked": 73802,
    "manual": 862,
    "idle": 0,
    "resumed": 0,
    "billable": 74664,
    "created_at": "2022-09-01T14:32:20.799309Z",
    "updated_at": "2022-09-02T11:00:48.637118Z",
    "username": "user9",
    "status": "active",
    "weekly_hours": 44,
    "three_weekly_hours": 20,
    "summaryWeekly": 74664,
    "summaryoverallWeekly": 43021,
    "dayliHoursDaily": 8,
    "summaryHoursTrackedWeekly": 21,
    "percentageHours": 5.185,
    "activityWeekly": 0,
    "percentageActivityWeekly": 14,
    "rolTittle": "DEV",
    "rolPriority": 0,
    "summaryStarts": 1,
    "percentActivityW": 41,
    "avergeHourWeekly": 5.1850000000000005
  },
  {
    "id": 6436683187,
    "task_id": 110916251,
    "user_id": 957963,
    "keyboard": 2050,
    "mouse": 5530,
    "input_tracked": 13478,
    "manual": 1181,
    "idle": 0,
    "resumed": 0,
    "billable": 14659,
    "created_at": "2022-09-03T14:05:12.543140Z",
    "updated_at": "2022-09-03T15:39:51.279106Z",
    "username": "user10",
    "status": "active",
    "weekly_hours": 44,
    "three_weekly_hours": 20,
    "summaryWeekly": 14659,
    "summaryoverallWeekly": 7182,
    "dayliHoursDaily": 8,
    "summaryHoursTrackedWeekly": 4,
    "percentageHours": 1.017986111111111,
    "activityWeekly": 0,
    "percentageActivityWeekly": 12,
    "rolTittle": "DEV",
    "rolPriority": 0,
    "summaryStarts": 0,
    "percentActivityW": 12,
    "avergeHourWeekly": 1.0175
  },
  {
    "id": 6415608216,
    "task_id": 110169040,
    "user_id": 1476078,
    "keyboard": 23401,
    "mouse": 51185,
    "input_tracked": 99108,
    "manual": 0,
    "idle": 0,
    "resumed": 0,
    "billable": 99108,
    "created_at": "2022-09-01T06:17:26.341286Z",
    "updated_at": "2022-09-02T02:03:01.258835Z",
    "username": "user11",
    "status": "active",
    "weekly_hours": 44,
    "three_weekly_hours": 20,
    "summaryWeekly": 99108,
    "summaryoverallWeekly": 67332,
    "dayliHoursDaily": 8,
    "summaryHoursTrackedWeekly": 28,
    "percentageHours": 6.882499999999999,
    "activityWeekly": 0,
    "percentageActivityWeekly": 17,
    "rolTittle": "DEV",
    "rolPriority": 0,
    "summaryStarts": 6,
    "percentActivityW": 48,
    "avergeHourWeekly": 6.885
  },
  {
    "id": 6436711920,
    "task_id": 111299925,
    "user_id": 1762379,
    "keyboard": 9260,
    "mouse": 27177,
    "input_tracked": 63034,
    "manual": 0,
    "idle": 0,
    "resumed": 0,
    "billable": 63034,
    "created_at": "2022-09-03T14:37:55.058824Z",
    "updated_at": "2022-09-04T11:00:09.826018Z",
    "username": "user12",
    "status": "active",
    "weekly_hours": 44,
    "three_weekly_hours": 20,
    "summaryWeekly": 63034,
    "summaryoverallWeekly": 33416,
    "dayliHoursDaily": 8,
    "summaryHoursTrackedWeekly": 18,
    "percentageHours": 4.377361111111111,
    "activityWeekly": 0,
    "percentageActivityWeekly": 13,
    "rolTittle": "DEV",
    "rolPriority": 0,
    "summaryStarts": 0,
    "percentActivityW": 40,
    "avergeHourWeekly": 4.3774999999999995
  },
  {
    "id": 6438388730,
    "task_id": 111271635,
    "user_id": 1763812,
    "keyboard": 8023,
    "mouse": 34217,
    "input_tracked": 60716,
    "manual": 3056,
    "idle": 0,
    "resumed": 0,
    "billable": 63772,
    "created_at": "2022-09-04T06:11:14.526669Z",
    "updated_at": "2022-09-04T11:00:10.753741Z",
    "username": "user13",
    "status": "active",
    "weekly_hours": 44,
    "three_weekly_hours": 20,
    "summaryWeekly": 63772,
    "summaryoverallWeekly": 39685,
    "dayliHoursDaily": 8,
    "summaryHoursTrackedWeekly": 18,
    "percentageHours": 4.4286111111111115,
    "activityWeekly": 0,
    "percentageActivityWeekly": 16,
    "rolTittle": "DEV",
    "rolPriority": 0,
    "summaryStarts": 0,
    "percentActivityW": 66,
    "avergeHourWeekly": 4.4275
  },
  {
    "id": 6436711572,
    "task_id": 110962406,
    "user_id": 1512574,
    "keyboard": 13031,
    "mouse": 29149,
    "input_tracked": 58021,
    "manual": 0,
    "idle": 0,
    "resumed": 0,
    "billable": 58021,
    "created_at": "2022-09-03T14:37:32.555344Z",
    "updated_at": "2022-09-04T11:00:12.010515Z",
    "username": "user14",
    "status": "active",
    "weekly_hours": 44,
    "three_weekly_hours": 20,
    "summaryWeekly": 58021,
    "summaryoverallWeekly": 35912,
    "dayliHoursDaily": 8,
    "summaryHoursTrackedWeekly": 16,
    "percentageHours": 4.0292361111111115,
    "activityWeekly": 0,
    "percentageActivityWeekly": 15,
    "rolTittle": "DEV",
    "rolPriority": 0,
    "summaryStarts": 0,
    "percentActivityW": 46,
    "avergeHourWeekly": 4.0275
  },
  {
    "id": 6429845321,
    "task_id": 111275770,
    "user_id": 1597423,
    "keyboard": 7547,
    "mouse": 16932,
    "input_tracked": 45344,
    "manual": 9000,
    "idle": 0,
    "resumed": 0,
    "billable": 45344,
    "created_at": "2022-09-02T15:02:22.445061Z",
    "updated_at": "2022-09-02T21:05:15.892875Z",
    "username": "user15",
    "status": "active",
    "weekly_hours": 44,
    "three_weekly_hours": 20,
    "summaryWeekly": 54344,
    "summaryoverallWeekly": 21515,
    "dayliHoursDaily": 8,
    "summaryHoursTrackedWeekly": 15,
    "percentageHours": 3.773888888888889,
    "activityWeekly": 0,
    "percentageActivityWeekly": 10,
    "rolTittle": "SAC",
    "rolPriority": 1,
    "summaryStarts": 0,
    "percentActivityW": 32,
    "avergeHourWeekly": 3.7724999999999995
  },
  {
    "id": 6429886569,
    "task_id": 111300959,
    "user_id": 1005008,
    "keyboard": 9124,
    "mouse": 23219,
    "input_tracked": 47335,
    "manual": 16930,
    "idle": 0,
    "resumed": 0,
    "billable": 64265,
    "created_at": "2022-09-02T15:10:49.050765Z",
    "updated_at": "2022-09-02T15:37:15.995376Z",
    "username": "user16",
    "status": "active",
    "weekly_hours": 44,
    "three_weekly_hours": 20,
    "summaryWeekly": 64265,
    "summaryoverallWeekly": 30503,
    "dayliHoursDaily": 8,
    "summaryHoursTrackedWeekly": 18,
    "percentageHours": 4.462847222222222,
    "activityWeekly": 0,
    "percentageActivityWeekly": 12,
    "rolTittle": "SAC",
    "rolPriority": 1,
    "summaryStarts": 0,
    "percentActivityW": 47,
    "avergeHourWeekly": 4.4625
  },
  {
    "id": 6418406327,
    "task_id": 110056072,
    "user_id": 1005014,
    "keyboard": 3338,
    "mouse": 24665,
    "input_tracked": 51343,
    "manual": 0,
    "idle": 0,
    "resumed": 0,
    "billable": 51343,
    "created_at": "2022-09-01T15:01:36.521321Z",
    "updated_at": "2022-09-01T15:35:14.010868Z",
    "username": "user17",
    "status": "active",
    "weekly_hours": 44,
    "three_weekly_hours": 20,
    "summaryWeekly": 51343,
    "summaryoverallWeekly": 27397,
    "dayliHoursDaily": 8,
    "summaryHoursTrackedWeekly": 14,
    "percentageHours": 3.565486111111111,
    "activityWeekly": 0,
    "percentageActivityWeekly": 13,
    "rolTittle": "SAC",
    "rolPriority": 1,
    "summaryStarts": 0,
    "percentActivityW": 62,
    "avergeHourWeekly": 3.5649999999999995
  },
  {
    "id": 6436728901,
    "task_id": 109755222,
    "user_id": 1846477,
    "keyboard": 9644,
    "mouse": 25906,
    "input_tracked": 64724,
    "manual": 0,
    "idle": 0,
    "resumed": 0,
    "billable": 64724,
    "created_at": "2022-09-03T14:57:43.250737Z",
    "updated_at": "2022-09-03T19:24:22.872994Z",
    "username": "user18",
    "status": "active",
    "weekly_hours": 44,
    "three_weekly_hours": 20,
    "summaryWeekly": 64724,
    "summaryoverallWeekly": 29885,
    "dayliHoursDaily": 8,
    "summaryHoursTrackedWeekly": 18,
    "percentageHours": 4.494722222222222,
    "activityWeekly": 0,
    "percentageActivityWeekly": 12,
    "rolTittle": "DESIGN",
    "rolPriority": 2,
    "summaryStarts": 0,
    "percentActivityW": 34,
    "avergeHourWeekly": 4.495
  },
  {
    "id": null,
    "task_id": null,
    "user_id": 1886674,
    "keyboard": 0,
    "mouse": 0,
    "input_tracked": 0,
    "manual": 0,
    "idle": 0,
    "resumed": 0,
    "billable": 0,
    "created_at": null,
    "updated_at": null,
    "username": "user19",
    "status": "active",
    "weekly_hours": 12.5,
    "three_weekly_hours": 7,
    "summaryWeekly": 0,
    "summaryoverallWeekly": 0,
    "dayliHoursDaily": 3,
    "summaryHoursTrackedWeekly": 0,
    "percentageHours": 0,
    "activityWeekly": 0,
    "percentageActivityWeekly": 0,
    "rolTittle": "DESIGN",
    "rolPriority": 2,
    "summaryStarts": 0,
    "percentActivityW": 0,
    "avergeHourWeekly": 0
  },
  {
    "id": null,
    "task_id": null,
    "user_id": 1931414,
    "keyboard": 0,
    "mouse": 0,
    "input_tracked": 0,
    "manual": 0,
    "idle": 0,
    "resumed": 0,
    "billable": 0,
    "created_at": null,
    "updated_at": null,
    "username": "user20",
    "status": "active",
    "weekly_hours": 12.5,
    "three_weekly_hours": 7,
    "summaryWeekly": 0,
    "summaryoverallWeekly": 0,
    "dayliHoursDaily": 3,
    "summaryHoursTrackedWeekly": 0,
    "percentageHours": 0,
    "activityWeekly": 0,
    "percentageActivityWeekly": 0,
    "rolTittle": "DESIGN",
    "rolPriority": 2,
    "summaryStarts": 0,
    "percentActivityW": 0,
    "avergeHourWeekly": 0
  },
  {
    "id": null,
    "task_id": null,
    "user_id": 766827,
    "keyboard": 0,
    "mouse": 0,
    "input_tracked": 0,
    "manual": 0,
    "idle": 0,
    "resumed": 0,
    "billable": 0,
    "created_at": null,
    "updated_at": null,
    "username": "user21",
    "status": "active",
    "weekly_hours": 12.5,
    "three_weekly_hours": 7,
    "summaryWeekly": 0,
    "summaryoverallWeekly": 0,
    "dayliHoursDaily": 3,
    "summaryHoursTrackedWeekly": 0,
    "percentageHours": 0,
    "activityWeekly": 0,
    "percentageActivityWeekly": 0,
    "rolTittle": "DESIGN",
    "rolPriority": 2,
    "summaryStarts": 0,
    "percentActivityW": 0,
    "avergeHourWeekly": 0
  }
]

const maplabels = apidata.map(element => element.username);
const labels = maplabels;

// DataBar
const mapbarHorizontal = apidata.map(element => element.summaryHoursTrackedWeekly);
const barHorizontal = mapbarHorizontal;
// console.log('labels', barHorizontal);

// LineBar
const maplineBar = apidata.map(element => element.percentActivityW);
const lineBar = maplineBar;

// BarWeeklyHour Colaborador
const mapColbWeekly = apidata.map(element => element.three_weekly_hours);
const colbWeekly = mapColbWeekly;

const subLabels = {
  id: 'subLabels',
  afterDatasetsDraw(chart, args, pluginOptions) {
    const {
      ctx,
      chartArea: {
        left,
        right,
        top,
        bottom,
        width,
        height
      }
    } = chart;

    ctx.save();
    subLabelText('DEV', width / 4 * 1.5);
    subLabelText('SAC', width / 4 * 3.1);
    subLabelText('DESIGN', width / 4 * 3.7);

    function subLabelText(text, x) {
      ctx.font = 'bold 12px sans-serif';
      ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(102, 102, 102, 1)';
      ctx.textAlign = 'center';
      ctx.fillText(text, x + left, bottom + 144);
      let xAxis = chart.scales['x-axis-0'];
      let xCenter = (xAxis.left + xAxis.right) / 1.45;
      let yBottom = chart.scales['y-axis-0'].bottom;
      ctx.strokeStyle = 'lightgray';
      [xAxis.left, xCenter, xAxis.right].forEach(x => {
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(x, yBottom);
        ctx.lineTo(x, yBottom + 110);
        ctx.stroke();
      });

      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.strokeStyle = 'lightgray';
      ctx.moveTo(width / 4 * 3.45, yBottom);
      ctx.lineTo(width / 4 * 3.45, yBottom + 110);
      ctx.stroke();

      ctx.restore();
    }



  }
}


const chart = new Chart(document.getElementById("chart"), {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: labels,
    datasets: [{
        type: 'line',
        label: '% ACTIVITY',
        backgroundColor: '#FF7605',
        borderColor: '#FF7605',
        data: lineBar,
        datalabels: {
          anchor: 'start',
          align: 'center',
          clamp: true,
          backgroundColor: '#FF7605',
          color: 'white',
          font: {
            weight: 'bold'
          }
        }
      },
      {
        type: 'bar',
        label: 'WEEKLY SUMMARY OF HOURS',
        backgroundColor: '#222A35',
        borderColor: '#222A35',
        data: barHorizontal,
        datalabels: {
          rotation: 270,
          padding: 10
        }

      },
      {
        type: 'bar',
        label: 'HOURS',
        backgroundColor: '#008582',
        borderColor: '#008582',
        data: colbWeekly,
        datalabels: {
          anchor: 'end',
          align: 'top',
          clamp: true,
          backgroundColor: '#008582',
          color: 'white',
          font: {
            weight: 'bold'
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  options: {
    plugins: {
      datalabels: {
        color: 'white',
        font: {
          weight: 'bold'
        },
      },
      title: {
        display: true,
        text: 'AVERAGE WEEKLY HOURS'
      }
    },
    elements: {
      line: {
        fill: false
      }
    },
    scales: {
      'x-axis-0': {
        stacked: true,
        min: 0,
        max: 80,
        ticks: {
          stepSize: 20,
          minRotation: 90
        },
        grid: {
          display: false
        }
      },
      'y-axis-0': {
        grid: {
          drawOnChartArea: true
        }
      }
    }
  },
  plugins: [subLabels]
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="/scripts/snippet-javascript-console.min.js?v=1"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@3.0.0/dist/chart.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-plugin-datalabels@2.0.0"></script>
  <canvas id="chart" height="200"></canvas>
</body>
```